# Code work in PyCharm but doesn't work when lauching through python console

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I have been working on a project and in the end it's suppose to print an output in a notepad file and it works perfectly in pycharm but as soon as I launch my file with python it crash every time I execute the code

I am 100% sure that the problem lies between the line I copied and pasted and I know that if start the project in pycharm with the python console setting active it work too so it may be some right problem? that's the conclusion I came with althought I'm not sure and I don't have any idea how to fix it even with my research. Ho and I,ve checked too and my python is up-to-date

```py
number_of_product = [0,0,0,0]
Total = 0
with open("Bill.txt", "w+") as Bill:
    Bill.write("{0} ChocoMilk\n".format(number_of_product[0]))
    Bill.write("{0} Katkit\n".format(number_of_product[1]))
    Bill.write("{0} N&N's\n".format(number_of_product[2]))
    Bill.write("{0} SourJoes\n".format(number_of_product[3]))
    Bill.write("Total : {0}$".format(Total))
```

The result should be 5 line of text written in a notepad file.

Comment: Did you try to run this code in a Python file from the console?

Comment: Can you edit your question to add some more details, specifically: how you're trying to run your code outside of PyCharm, and what you mean by "crash"? Are you getting error messages? If so, could you tell us what they say? If you're getting a traceback from a Python error that would be helpful as well. Without any extra info it's really hard for us to know what the problem is.

Comment: Don't post the solution in the question. Add an answer (and mark it as a solution) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: I was opening the Pycharm file by clicking "Open with" python3.7 and Windows wasn't giving me all the right I needed.

You need to change the basic application that runs the program from Pycharm to Python itself.